# Spigot Minecraft plugin coding NoClassDefFound error mysql

Tags: java, mysql, minecraft

When i start the server this error comes : 
I am using IntelliJ Idea and MySQL jar is added to the src and in the project modules.

[Error pastebin](https://pastebin.com/PLjKDu3g)

Here is my code

```
package com.okaam.jaajhome;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import pro.husk.mysql.MySQL;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JaaJHome extends JavaPlugin {
 static JaaJHome instance = null;

    MySQL MySQL = new MySQL("address", "port", "schema", "user", "password", "");
    static Connection c = null;

 @Override
    public void onEnable() {
     System.out.println("Plugin JaaJHome active");
     getCommand("sethome").setExecutor(new SetHomeExecutor());
     getCommand("home").setExecutor(new HomeExecutor());
     try {
         c = MySQL.getConnection();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     instance = this;
 }

    public static JaaJHome getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're missing on some dependencies, make sure you have them either in the plugins folder as a non plugin or in the classpath to make sure they're loaded.